# Validating the attribute target from the attribute code

Tags: c#, silverlight, attributes

Need to verify that the attribute can be applied only to a **class** that implements a certain *interface*. Googled on that and couldn't find any way to access the *type* of the target class from the attribute code.

Is there any easy way to do that, please?

[optional] Is there a "portable" way (I mean, it would be totally great if the code will be compiled both in C# and Silverlight)?

**update**: I could pass the target class type as one of the attribute arguments, but I don't want to trust on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently only `PostSharp` aspects can help, but the trade off will be bigger the the benefit.